# c# MySql data to list

Tags: c#, mysql, list

basically what I want to do is **read data from the table** and then **add that data to the appropriate list**.

For example

```
List<int> value;
SELECT Values_To_Add FROM table
value.add(Values_To_Add)
```

Obviously using the correct C# MySql syntax. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like the below might what you are looking for:

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();

string sql = "SELECT Values_To_Add FROM table";
command.CommandText = sql;
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
  values.Add(reader["Values_To_Add "]);
}
```

You might what to Google about setting up MySqlReader etc.

Hope this helps, it should be a start.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<int> values;

var result = from value in table
             select value;

foreach(var item in result) values.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the `SQLDataReader` Class.

After researching you should be able to use the data reader to read in rows from your table and subsequently add them to your list :)

Tutorial: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx